# Version control for graphics alongside iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

I'm working on my first iOS app and have decided to stop being irresponsible and do a good job with version control. My project has been migrated over to a new repository that I established with the DP of Xcode 5. There are a number of images that I've created with Paint Code and Pixelmator that most certainly deserve the same attention to version control as the source code for the app. I love having git hidden behind the UI of xcode - Is there a clean way to include other random files (like Pixelmator files for example) in the same repository as my iOS project and have it all maintained together? Presumably this would not happen in xcode. Don't want any files left out of the party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) or the command line for this. Every other git tool should work fine too.

You don't have to (and honestly, you should not) add your assets (.psd, .ai, .pxm, etc) to Xcode. Just commit them without Xcode.

I do exactly this since a couple of years. All my "raw" files go into an "assets" folder in the root folder of my project. Those files are not added to Xcode, I manage them with SourceTree.

Actually I manage the whole project with SourceTree. I don't use Xcodes Source Control features at all. The git support in Xcode is really basic if you compare it to SourceTree.
Once you've used "Stage Selected Lines" and "Stage Hunk" in SourceTree you can't go back to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I put my graphic work files in a folder alongside Resources, but i exclude it and all its content from the target(s). Works for me (using Git).

Answer (score 0):

Can't talk about Xcode 5 here since it's NDA - check out the developer forums for more info (once they get unborked from the hack attempt).

In every recent project I've worked on, we have just included the files in the git repository. Git handles binary files like images just fine, so Xcode should pickup the fact that they're modified and you'll be able to commit them. I personally use the command line 90% of the time, and the other 10% of the time I use SourceTree (for merging / conflict resolution).